# System.Data.SqlClient 4.6.0 in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm currently using System.Data.SqlClient 4.5.1 in my Azure Functions but I would like to use 4.6.0, as it supports Access Tokens. The last two preview releases also supported Access Tokens, I believe. The feature was committed to the .NET Core repository back in June. I'm not sure what the difference is between the NuGet packages and the .NET Core Framework itself. The Azure Functions local runtime for debugging claims neither 4.6.0 or the preview releases are supported on the platform. Any ideas?

Comment: I could never use 4.6.0 in Azure functions... Always had to settle for 4.5.1

Comment: Hi James, do you need further help? If my solution works for you could you accept it for others to refer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems some problem when it comes to references related to runtime assemblies, check this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3568).

So the workaround is to load the assemblies on our own. Right click on Function project and `Edit <FunctionAppName>.csproj`, add items below to copy related assemblies to output dir.

```
  <!-- For publish -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.data.sqlclient\4.6.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.1\System.Data.SqlClient.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- For local debug -->
  <Target Name="CopyToBin" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.data.sqlclient\4.6.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.1\System.Data.SqlClient.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\bin" />
  </Target>
```